# Solving a shifted Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the Laplace equation $(a-\nabla^{2})\phi(x,y)=0$. I am trying to solve it for the half plane boundary by using methods of images. The first term, constant $a$, is a problem for me. I know without this term I have the Greens function $G(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}Log[\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}+(y-y_{0})^{2}}{(x-x_{0})^{2}+(y+y_{0})^{2}}]$ and this satisfy $\nabla^{2}G(x,y)=\delta(x-x_{0})\delta(y-y_{0})$. However this is only satisfied for $a=0$. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the boundary condition?

Comment: @ Chee Han $\phi(x,y)$ is defined on upper half plane. $y>0$

Comment: Have you Googled solutions to the Helmholtz equation? There is plenty of information about Greens functions for it.

Comment: @Chee Han @ Mattos. Thanks. I figure out how to solve this equation. This is solved by $\phi'(x,y)=\exp(i\lambda_{i}x_{i})\phi(x,y)$. The Greens function for this case will be $G(x,y)=-i\frac{\exp(i\lambda_{i}x_{i})}{2\pi}Log[\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}+(y-y_{0})^{2}}{(x-x_{0})^{2}+(y+y_{0})^{2}}]$, where $\sqrt{\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}}=a$.